# JAVA 8 filter list of object with any matching property

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

My requirement is to filter a list of objects by a string matching any of the properties.
For example, let say `Contact` class has three properties: street, city, phone.

I am aware of how java stream filter works, where i have to compare the input string with each property as below:

```
contactList.stream().filter(contact -> contact.getStreet().equals("dubai") || 
                            contact.getCity().equals("dubai") || .......).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, if a class has 20+ properties and size of list 80,000+, comparing each property with the input string would affect the performance. So my question is, does Java or any other library support filtering the list with any matching property? Something as below:

```
contactList.stream().filter(contact -> contact.anyProperty.equals("dubai").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can someone help me on this, thanks.

Comment: Seems like you need full-text search in your database. Have you considered/investigated that?

Comment: There is no library that can eliminate the fundamental operation necessary for the task. You want all properties checked, you need to check all properties. Any better looking solution only hides the actual work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `findAny`. This will end as soon as the candidate is found:

```
Optional<Contact> contact = contactList.stream().filter(contact -> contact.getStreet().equals("dubai") || 
                        contact.getCity().equals("dubai") || .......).findAny();
```

Or if you only need an information if such an object exists, use `anyMatch`:

```
boolean exists = contactList.stream().anyMatch(contact -> contact.getStreet().equals("dubai") || 
                        contact.getCity().equals("dubai") || .......);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can solve this by using reflection to read all class properties

or

By overriding toString() method and check if the result of to String contains input string

Comment: Thanks, toString() will be the simple trick, i will check the performance.

Comment: Obviously, concatenating 20+ properties to a string to search it, is more work than just comparing the 20+ properties.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way would be to override `toString()` with required properties and use it to check if it contains a word,

```
contactList.stream()
    .filter(contact -> contact.toString().contains("dubai"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may also want to use `Pattern` to match the exact word.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that use Gson and JSON, when I read your question, the first thing I think of is:

1. Convert your list to a JsonArray of JsonObject => You can easily get the keyset of each JsonObject (the properties list of your contact object)
2. Filter in that list, find all JsonObject that has the value "dubai"

Comment: Can you please share how to filter JsonObjects, and get the ids for the filtered objects

Comment: convert to a json text: `String json = new Gson().toJson(yourList);`
convert to a json array: `JsonArray arr = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();`

JsonArray is an Iterable, it's elements are JsonElement, which can convert to JsonObject via `.getAsJsonObject()`

And JsonObject has "entrySet()`

Try use them yourself

Comment: Thanks, will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the code blocked your problem is resolved.

```
contactList.stream().anyMatch(contact -> contactMacther(contact,"dubai"));
private boolean contactMacther(Contact contact, String match){
    return contact.getStreet().equalsIgnoreCase(match) ||
            contact.getCity().equalsIgnoreCase(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create list of functions that extract properties, than use it in your filter method:

```java
List<Function<Contact, Object>> getPrperties = Arrays.asList(
        Contact::getStreet, 
        Contact::getCity
        // other
        );

contactList.stream()
        .filter(contact -> getPrperties.stream()
                .map(f -> f.apply(contact))
                .anyMatch("dubai"::equals)
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Or you can extract test method:

```
BiFunction<Contact, String, Boolean> test = (contact, values) ->
        getPrperties.stream().map(f -> f.apply(contact)).anyMatch(values::equals);

List<Person> collect = contactList.stream()
        .filter(contact -> test.apply(contact, "dubai"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```